# Svn checkout fail - subversion execption

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I got a new computer and I had to check my old work imported from my previous computer using SVN.
For some reason for which I cant find an answer, checkout gets an error every time. 
This is the error message I get from the button (all the rest is just the way they want me to report that error).
So I'm getting : Subversion Exeption.

```
In file
 'D:\Development\SVN\Releases\TortoiseSVN-1.8.0\ext\subversion\subversion\libsvn_client\ra.c'
 line 647: assertion failed (peg_revnum != SVN_INVALID_REVNUM)
```

any ideas?

Comment: The second message on this page has possibly a solution to your problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/subversion_users/56-vN8eUuFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe TortoiseSVN 1.8 is newer for your old work repository.

Try old version client (or upgrade your server's svn, **after backup repositories** ).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was version of tortoise diffrences, just downloaded the old version i had..